# .Net framework 4.7.2 to netcoreapp2.0 comparability issues

Tags: c#, .net-core

I wrote application in .net frawork 4.7.2 to get the file from TFS update and check-in the same.

Now need to add same below code in netcoreapp2.0, which is working as a expected in .NetFrawork 4.7.2. but getting below issues, when working with netcoreapp2.0

> I have added System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, System.Core dll's as well

## Here is the code..

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

```
string test = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
String localDir = @"c:\Download\1\" + test.ToString() + "";

TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(http://tfs2:8080/));
VersionControlServer sourceControl = (VersionControlServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
Workspace sourceControlWorkspace = sourceControl.CreateWorkspace(test.ToString(), sourceControl.AuthorizedUser);
sourceControlWorkspace.Map("$/tfs/SAutomation/abc.xml", localDir);
sourceControlWorkspace.Get();
var items = sourceControl.GetItems("$/tfs/SAutomation/abc.xml", VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full)
                            .Items;
return items;
```

Comment: Which line throws? The call stack doesn't match the code. In any case none of those types is available out of the box with .NET Core (or 4.7.2). How did you add them? Are they your own? Did you use a package? Or a direct reference to Full framework assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Its only a guess, though you probably need to add the appropriate nuget

[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/)

> Provides types that support using configuration files.
>
> Commonly Used Types: System.Configuration.Configuration
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Comment: Thanks Saruman, I have added System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager but still facing some other dll issues. I used this two dlls using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;  is this DLL's are compatible with .NetCoreApp2.0

Comment: @BhupalGoud ok i am glad it helped, if you cant solve then it would probably be best to make a new question with the issues